# Cannot get image (ASP.NET)

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have View where I need to get src value for pic from db.

Here is View code

```
   <tbody id="findings" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="point">
                            @(rowNo += 1)
                        </td>
                        <td style="display:none" id="patientId" class="title">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient_id)
                        </td>

                        <td class="title">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.Date_of_Birthday)
                        </td>
                        <td id="nameVal" class="title">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Patient.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td class="title">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Start_appointment)
                        </td>
                        <td class="title">
                            <img src="@item.Calculation.CalculationStatus" />
                        </td>
                        <td class="title"></td>
                        <td class="title"></td>
                    </tr>
                 }
            </tbody>
```

But when I run I have error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

In page source I have this `<td class="title">
                                <img src="~/images/status_icons/openedCalculation.png" />
                            </td>`

I don't understand why page not showing.

Comment: Can you show us where you have located that file? Given the path, the images folder should be situated at the root of your web project.

Comment: For the testing purpose, type the full absolute path to the resource image file.

Comment: Have you checked that the file really exists? A 404 indicates that the resource (page/image/...) was not found at the specified location.

Comment: Yes. Pic is in root of project@hbulens

Comment: Yes. It exists@Abbas

Comment: Problem was at `~` symbol. Without it, all ok

Comment: yes, because this is plain html, not a server side tag. Nothing is going to replace that `~` symbol. Try `<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/status_icons/openedCalculation.png")" />`

Answer (score 0):

Problem was at `~` symbol. Without it, all will be working.

Comment: yes, but if you just remove that `~` it will work only if `images` is at root server level. In other words, if you deploy this at a server like http://mywebsite.com/myapplication, since images is a folder of myapplication, it's not going to find it.